# Getting 401 unauthorized error While Generating request_token request

Tags: twitter-oauth

I am attempting to generate a request token by POSTing to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, but I cannot seem to get any response other than an http 401 error

My Authorization: header looks like this:

```
Authorization : OAuth oauth_callback="https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback",oauth_consumer_key="XX",oauth_nonce="XX",oauth_signature="XX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="XX",oauth_version="1.0"
```

Anybody have any idea how to get this to work?